# problem with awk script

Tags: shell, awk

when I call my awk script, I keep getting an error :

```
sam@sam-laptop:~/shell/td4$ awk -f agenda.awk -- -n Robert agenda.txt
awk: agenda.awk:6: printf "Hello"
awk: agenda.awk:6: ^ syntax error
```

the script contains this :

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN {
}

printf "Hello"

END {
}
```

Thank you

Comment: with $awk -f agenda.awk agenda.txt it works fine, but i want to add command line arguments to my awk script.. so that my program searchs the agenda for a name with -n or an e-mail with -m... How do I do that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to wrap it in {}

```
BEGIN {
}
{
 printf "Hello"
}
END {
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks, but now i'm getting this error : awk: fatal: cannot open file `-n' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do with the -- and -n Robert, but if you want to use agenda.txt as the source input just do: awk -f agenda.awk agenda.txt

Comment: with  $awk -f agenda.awk agenda.txt 
it works fine, but i want to add command line arguments to my awk script.. so that my program searchs the agenda for a name with -n or an e-mail with -m... How do I do that ? Thank you !

Comment: adding arguments you use the "-v" option like so: awk -f agenda.awk -v name=Robert -v email=robert@email.com agenda.txt

Comment: glad to help :-) awk is my favorite language

Answer (score 0):

i think you also need to modify the shebang as

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```